# Status of Java directory WatchService on MacOS

Tags: java, macos

What is the status for WatchService on the Java platform for MacOS?

Seems not to have been working on 7 and 8.

Has that been resolved in later versions? We are on 13 now.

Comment: Hi momomo, can you clarify what you mean by "the status for WatchService"?

Comment: It was not properly implemented. It's an API that notifies of file changes. Not a native implementation on 8. Slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, it's working on MacOS with OpenJDK 8.

```
/tmp$ java DirectoryWatcherExample                        
Event kind:ENTRY_CREATE. File affected: test.txt.                               
Event kind:ENTRY_DELETE. File affected: test.txt.                               
Event kind:ENTRY_CREATE. File affected: test.txt.                               
Event kind:ENTRY_MODIFY. File affected: test.txt.                               
Event kind:ENTRY_DELETE. File affected: test.txt.                               

/tmp$ java -version                                     
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"                                                     
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_232-b09)                 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)          

/tmp$ uname -v                                            
Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Sat Oct 12 00:02:19 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.278.12
~1/RELEASE_X86_64
```

You can try the code out [DirectoryWatcherExample.java](https://gist.github.com/prateeknischal/d397fba1c7baeb990d620a3fdcc2f6d8)

Original source: [A guide to WatchService in Java NIO2](https://www.baeldung.com/java-nio2-watchservice)

JDK seems to have the implementation of a mechanism called [kevent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue) which is the notification mechanism for OpenBSD/solaris based systems. I have no experience with searching mercurial repos, so the best I can find is a readonly JDK8 source that shows the kqueue implementation.

- [Kqueue.java](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/solaris/classes/sun/nio/ch/KQueue.java)
- Related to the native implementation; [KQueueArrayWrapper.c](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/macosx/native/sun/nio/ch/KQueueArrayWrapper.c)
- Macos manpage for [`kevent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/kevent.2.html)

Comment: Yes, maybe. I think it is just incredibly slow so I did not pick up on the changes. It is not a native implementation.